# Accessing items list in API call if asynchronous

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api

I am building a weather app with React and Redux. When I want to display the weather for the next 5 days of a given city I make the API call which will get a list of several weather parameters for a sequence of hours. I can access only those enclosed in the list[0] element, since the others are not yet created. How to access them? I thought about a set interval function but I cannot set it up. Any suggestion?

Weather component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Chart from '../components/chart';
import GoogleMap from '../components/google_map';

class WeatherList extends Component {
    renderWeather(cityData) {
        const temps = _.map(cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.temp), (temp) => temp - 273);
        const pressure = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.pressure);
        const humidity = cityData.list.map(weather => weather.main.humidity);
        const day1 = cityData.list[0].weather[0].description;
        const day2 = cityData.list[1].weather[2].description;
        const day3 = cityData.list[2].weather[2].description;         
        const lon = cityData.city.coord.lon;
        const lat = cityData.city.coord.lat;

        return (
            <tr key={cityData.city.name}>
                <td><GoogleMap lon={lon} lat={lat}/></td>
                <td>{day1}</td>
                <td>{day2}</td>
                <td>{day3}</td>
                <td><Chart data={temps} color="orange" units="°"/></td>
                <td><Chart data={pressure} color="yellow" units="hPa"/></td>
                <td><Chart data={humidity} color="green" units="%"/></td>

            </tr>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table className="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Overall Weather</th>
                        <th>Pressure (hPa)</th>
                        <th>Humidity (%)</th>
                        <th>Temperature (k)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { weather: state.weather };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

API Call Action Creator

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_KEY = 'ce6111c5cb481755173214d6bf62f51a';
const ROOT_URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city) {
    const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},it`;
    const request = axios.get(url);

    return {
        type: 'FETCH_WEATHER',
        payload: request
    };
}
```

Reducer for the FETCH_WEATHER call

```
import { FETCH_WEATHER } from '../actions/index';

export default function (state= [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {

    case FETCH_WEATHER:
        return state.concat([action.payload.data]);    
    }     
    return state;
}
```

[image: image of the list]

Comment: Are you using a redux middleware? That's an easier way to get asynchronous functionality. I suggest redux-saga

Comment: I am, I am suing redux-promise...what is wierd is that when i use the map method to make an average of the temperatures across the list it works, accessing all the list elements. The problem is when I try to access directly one element on the list which is not the first one. In this case on the console it says is not possible to read the property of something undefined

Comment: Yes this happened to me also, I use redux-saga middleware. My solution was modify the reducer to get the specific data.
E.g. `temperature: action.data.temperature[0]` or in your case you will need to map it to return an array.

Comment: But reading your problem again, I believe you have an issue related to a promise. Can you show how you are using redux-promise?

Comment: I updated with the reducer I used for the API call

Comment: I haven't used `redux-promise`, but looking at the docs https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-promise/blob/master/README.md are you using `await`, `promise` etc... In your actions? Or else you will get the first data provided, but not the rest as their is no promise to fetch the others after the first.

Comment: To be honest I am not using that...as you can see I just call the plain data in the render method. Can you briefly explain how should I use the await method to properly render the list item which is not syncronous?